# How do I edit DHCP settings, etc, on PlusNet's 2704n router?

Tags: router

Recently upgraded to [PlusNet Fibre](https://www.plus.net/home-broadband/fibre/), and with it a PlusNet router.  It appears this is a rebadged [Sagemcom 2704N](http://www.sagemcom.com/broadband/gateways/dsl-gateways/fst-1704n-2704n/).

There is 'Advanced Settings', where first I have to acknowledge 'Please proceed with caution! Changing settings in this area may affect your Broadband service.' but that only opens some things; I still cannot find a way to disable the DHCP server or even reduce the address reservation range.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the answer after some serious reading of other forums; will post here for completeness.

It's as simple as using http://192.168.1.254/expert_user.html (assuming your router still has its default address, if not replace with the IP address of your router) (from page 9 of [this](http://community.plus.net/forum/index.php/topic,135846.128.html) thread)

Comment: thanks for this, we just got plusnet as a backup circuit, and I didn't want to renumber any devices with static IPs.